# Why is fast-forward merge relevant in GitHub rebase & merge workflow

Tags: git, github

I'm reading the [following doc](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/):

> When you select the Rebase and merge option on a pull request on
>   GitHub, all commits from the topic branch (or head branch) are added
>   onto the base branch individually without a merge commit. Pull
>   requests with rebased commits are merged **using the fast-forward
>   option**.

I can't seem to understand why the fast-forward option is relevant here.

Suppose I have the following:

```
x---x (topic)
 \
  \
   x (head)
```

And now I want to rebase `topic` onto `head` so the log it will look like this:

```
x
 \
  \
   x (head) --- x' (topic)
```

Where does `fast-forward` come into play here?

Comment: I think the docs want to make it clear that there will be no actual merge commit after the "merge" (itself preceded by a rebase) is performed, so someone looking at the branch will see just a collection of commits. See the `--no-ff` flag for the alternative.

Comment: @user4815162342, thanks, so what you're saying is that it's not about some existing git command like `git rebase --ff` (which doesn't exist), but it's rather used to contrast it with real `git merge --no-ff` option described in the first `true merge` strategy?

Comment: Yes. The very first option described at the top of the page, *Merge pull requests*, explicitly documents that "the pull request is merged using the `--no-ff` option." This means that with the default option you can count on the merge commit delineating the merge (and announcing the merge author etc) even if it technically *could* be performed as a fast-forward merge. With rebase it's the other way around: you are guaranteed to get a linear collection of commits without a merge commit anywhere in sight.

Comment: @user4815162342, got it, thanks. It's definitely confusing wording. And they probably use this same approach when describing `squash&merge` in the second strategy - _Pull requests with squashed commits are merged using the fast-forward option._? Merging squashed commits is akin to squashed rebasing without moving the branch so can't see where `fast-forward` option is used here.